# How to fill in "install_flags" field in salt-stack when installing applications in Windows?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm using salt-stack to manage the minion in Windows.
I'm wondering that how to fill in `install_flags` field in salt-stack when installing applications in Windows?

Here is the document of salt-stack.
http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/windows-package-manager.html
You may see that: for installation, Firefox gets `-ms` and 7zip gets `/q` as their own `install_flags`.

Is there a rule to follow? i.e. "*If I want to install apache-tomcat, what's the install_flags to fill in?*"

Is there someone knows the secret?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried what the documentation suggests? Create a file called "/srv/salt/win/repo/apache-tomcat/init.sls" and then regenerate the cache? Of course this assumes you have an executable or MSI package for apache.... Or do you? If not I would suggest try installing Apache using the standard Salt stack state file. Should work. Apologies in advance if this posting is dismissive. I'll admit I rarely work on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of Salt Windows package manager. Those install_flags refer to the silent install options that your application installer provides. Sometimes passing a  /? or /h to the installer at the command line will tell you what options are available.

Also, the wpkg project has a fantastic wiki documenting many of the silent installer switches here: http://wpkg.org/Category:Silent_Installers

A quick Google search revealed this doc as well: http://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite8_ga/System_Management_Hub/install/tomcat_windows_install.htm#d0e2149

Comment: I've added a note about this to the Salt docs.
http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/windows-package-manager.html

Comment: Thank you, Dave. It helps a lot!! :)

Comment: You're welcome!  Would you mind marking your question as answered?  Thanks!